Create dynamic class and second parameter type based on first
I have a number of classes that I'll need to create instances of based on a string. Each class has a model that needs to be passed in their constructor and they are all different (some similar properties, but we'll keep it simple).
I am trying to create a method that allows two parameters: one to determine what class is to be instantiated; and the second parameter should be narrowed to the model needed for that class.
For example if I pass MenuElementEnum.Products as the first parameter, you should only then be allowed to pass a ProductModel object as the second parameter.
enum MenuElement {
    Categories = 'Categories',
    Products = 'Products',
}

type ProductModel = {
  name:string;
  age:number
   id:string;
}
type CategoryModel = {
  name:string;
  favorite:boolean
   id:string;
}

class Product implements ProductModel{
  name =''
  age= 0;
  id = '';

  constructor(model:ProductModel)
  {
  }
}

class Category implements CategoryModel{
  name=''
  favorite=true
  id=''

  constructor(model:CategoryModel)
  {
  }
}

const MenuElements = {
  [MenuElementEnum.Products]:Product,
  [MenuElementEnum.Categories]:Category
}

type KeysInEnum = keyof typeof MenuElementEnum

type ModelTypeForNewElement<Z extends keyof typeof MenuElements, Type extends typeof MenuElements[Z]> = {
    [Prop in keyof Type]: Type[Prop];
}

type GEN = keyof typeof MenuElementEnum;

class DynamicMenuElement {
    static instance: DynamicMenuElement;

    public static get() {
        if (!DynamicMenuElement.instance) {
            DynamicMenuElement.instance = new DynamicMenuElement();
        }
        return DynamicMenuElement.instance;
    }

    public createMenuElement<T extends GEN>(type: T, model: ModelTypeForNewElement<T,typeof MenuElements[T]>) {

        const ElementType = MenuElements[type]
        if (!ElementType) {

            throw new Error(`Cannot find the class type of ${type}`);
        }
        return new ElementType(model);

    }
}

const creator = DynamicMenuElement.get();

creator.createMenuElement(MenuElementEnum.Categories,/*code hinting says a Category [model] is required here (expected) */)

creator.createMenuElement(MenuElementEnum.Product,/*code hinting says a Product [model] is required here (expected) */)


What is happening here.. the ElementType is merging both models like this:
const ElementType: new (model: ProductModel & CategoryModel) => Product | Category

When what I was expecting/wanting is:
(model:ProductModel | CategoryModel) => Product | Category

I've tried all sorts of different approaches. This is the closest I've come.  I don't know why the argument "model" is being declared as all of my type aliases squished together:
(model:ProductModel | CategoryModel) => Product | Category

and not:
(model:ProductModel & CategoryModel) => Product | Category

EDIT:
The code jcalz wrote in his answer satisfies this..
TS Playground.

• Screenshots of IDEs are unfortunately not appropriate here. Please replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions. • Your const MenuElementEnum initializer is syntactically invalid. Please [edit] to make sure your code is a [mre].

(Please see prev comment and make appropriate edits.) TS can't model correlations the way you're doing it. The only supported approach is described at ms/TS#47109. I can use your existing MenuElements and express the types in the way TS understands, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what am I missing?

I'm still working through this example.. I'm not at all understanding how  MenuElementsParam and MenuElementsReturn are working, so its difficult to say.. It does appear to be the desired result though..  I think that using the 'new' operator as the type of the type alias member is a bit confusing for me..
[K in keyof _MenuElements]: _MenuElements[K] extends *new* (arg: infer A) => any ? A : never

• Your const MenuElementEnum initializer is still syntactically invalid; is it supposed to be a const (in which case you need to fix the initializer) or an enum (in which case you should write that instead)? •  Are you saying you can't tell if my approach addresses the question unless I explain exactly how it works first? Seems like a catch-22, since I don't want to write up a full explanation for something that turns out not to be what you're trying to do. I'm happy to explain it when I write an actual answer. What do you think?

yeah sorry, it is actually an enum in my code. I'm not sure why I changed that.. I believe it does address my question and just have no idea what those 3 types you wrote work, haha.  If you could write a detailed answer I would very much appreciate it. I sort of understand 'infer' - but not in this context; nor do I understand what/how/why you've used the 'new' operator in those types. Thank you!

I'm going to write up an answer but it would be very very helpful if you'd take your example code, drop it into an IDE, and make sure it demonstrates what you say it does. You've changed the name of the enum but not references to it, and now there are other errors in your generics. Could you please [edit] it so the only issue is the one you're referencing? Note that I'm asking you to use an IDE so that you don't inadvertently introduce another problem or fail to find an existing one.

(see prev comment) your code doesn't have a functioning ModelTypeForNewElement either, since it is apparently expecting you to pass in the constructor, like creator.createMenuElement(MenuElement.Categories, Category) instead of, I presume, creator.createMenuElement(MenuElement.Categories, { favorite: true, id: "abc", name: "" }).  This really needs to be fixed in the question, or else it's not demonstrating at all the problem you're having.

The problem is that TypeScript can't look at the type of MenuElements and see that, for an arbitrary generic key type, you can write new MenuElements[type](model) where model is the expected input corresponding to the constructor. It doesn't see the abstract correlation between type and model. So it ends up widening MenuElements[type] to its constraint, which is the union typeof Product | typeof Category.  And unions of functions/constructors require intersections of arguments to be called safely (see the TypeScript 3.3 release notes describing this feature).
TypeScript's inability to follow correlated unions is described at microsoft/TypeScript#30581.

The recommended approach to deal with it is described at microsoft/TypeScript#47109.
The idea is that you need to write the type of MenuElements so that it's explicitly a single structure for every key.  You do this by making it a mapped type.  So you'll need const MenuElements: { [K in ⋯]: ⋯ } = .  And the property type of that mapped type needs to be a construct signature that relates some a particular constructor input that depends on K to a particular instance type that also depends on K.  So it should look like
const MenuElements: { [K in keyof MenuElementsParam]:
    new (arg: MenuElementsParam[K]) => MenuElementsReturn[K]
} = {
    [MenuElement.Products]: Product,
    [MenuElement.Categories]: Category
};

type MenuElementsParam = {
    [MenuElement.Products]: ProductModel;
    [MenuElement.Categories]: CategoryModel;
}

type MenuElementsReturn = {
    [MenuElement.Products]: Product;
    [MenuElement.Categories]: Category;
}

And if you do that, you can use MenuElementsParam directly instead of the complicated ModelTypeForNewElement type in the call signature for createMenuElement:
function createMenuElement<K extends keyof MenuElementsParam>(
    type: K, model: MenuElementsParam[K]
) {

    const ElementType = MenuElements[type]
    if (!ElementType) {
        throw new Error(`Cannot find the class type of ${type}`);
    }
    return new ElementType(model); // okay, works

}

And if you inspect the call signature, you'll see it returns MenuElementsReturn[K]:
/* function createMenuElement<K extends keyof MenuElementsParam>(
     type: K, model: MenuElementsParam[K]): MenuElementsReturn[K] */

Which gives you the behavior you're looking for:
const cat = createMenuElement(MenuElement.Categories, { favorite: true, id: "", name: "" });
//    ^? const cat: Category
const pro = createMenuElement(MenuElement.Products, { age: 123, id: "", name: "" });
//    ^? const pro: Product


That answers the question, but if you decide to add another property to MenuElements you'll be required to do a bunch of boilerplate changes to MenuElementsParam and MenuElementsReturn.  It would be nicer if you could just write MenuElements and then have TypeScript compute MenuElementsParam and MenuElementsReturn from it.
And this is indeed possible, with the caveat that you'll need to initialize MenuElements in a different variable so that we can later annotate the type of the MenuElements variable. So let's stick with your original MenuElements but rename it out of the way:
const _MenuElements = {
    [MenuElement.Products]: Product,
    [MenuElement.Categories]: Category
}

And let's inspect its type:
type _MenuElements = typeof _MenuElements;

From here we need to pull out the parameter and return types of the constructors. We can do that using the ConstructorParameters and InstanceType utility types:
type MenuElementsParam = 
  { [K in keyof _MenuElements]: ConstructorParameters<_MenuElements[K]>[0] }

type MenuElementsReturn = 
  { [K in keyof _MenuElements]: InstanceType<_MenuElements[K]> }

(noting that ConstructorParameters gives the tuple of all parameters, but since you only have one and you want to grab that one, we have to index into that tuple with 0 to get the first parameter.)
Or we can write them out ourselves using the conditional type inference, which is how those utility types are defined anyway:
type MenuElementsParam = { [K in keyof _MenuElements]:
    _MenuElements[K] extends new (arg: infer A) => any ? A : never
}

type MenuElementsReturn = { [K in keyof _MenuElements]:
    _MenuElements[K] extends new (arg: any) => infer R ? R : never
}

This is just checking _MenuElements[K] against a construct signature new (arg: any) => any) and inferring the piece we care about. Both definitions result in types equivalent to the manually-defined versions, but now if _MenuElements changes, these will automatically change.
Finally we can annotate MenuElements as the same mapped type as before, but now we initialize it with the value of _MenuElements:
const MenuElements: { [K in keyof _MenuElements]:
    new (arg: MenuElementsParam[K]) => MenuElementsReturn[K]
} = _MenuElements;

And we're done. The createMenuElement() function type-checks both for callers and for the implementation.

Playground link to code

Question about the inference. when you say _MenuElements[K] extends new (arg: infer A) => any ? A : never  where is the inference coming from? is it inferring from _MenuElements[K] ?  aka new Product/Category(HERE?)

Yes. Please look at the documentation for inferring within conditional types.

Hmm I'm running in to an issue with implementation. the issue is that the first parameter will be dynamic. which is the reason for this whole thing. I'm unable to set in a variable, ie. const c = dynamicClass.get().createMenuElement(SOME_VAR_HERE, SOME_MODEL_HERE) where SOME_VAR_HERE would be determined upstream.
works fine if you createMenuElement(MenuElementEnum.Product, ...)

I'm not sure how to proceed here without a [mre]. Note that last I left it, I asked you to [edit] the question to fix the continued issues with the code not being a [mre], so this would be a great time for you to do that.

used a codepen to show you as best I could, what I'm trying to do. please refer to the edit comment in my OP. Note... codepen doesn't complain with what I've written, but vscode and ts plugin sure do. it makes sense why but I am unsure how to resolve it. I've left a comment where the issue lies in the codepen

Looking at the TS playground version of your code I see lots of errors you're not asking about. I don't know how to start unless the only errors are the ones you're asking about. Furthermore, you're starting with my answer, meaning this is a followup question and belongs in a new post, not expanding the scope here. If you're going to edit the question, please do so by making it a [mre] of your original issue, with consistent naming (MenuElementEnum vs MenuElement) and a functioning ModelTypeForNewElement. Until I see that I can't proceed, sorry.

After reviewing some other things, it turned out there was some issue with a specific class (not in this example - in my source) that was inheriting incorrectly. I've finalized the working example and added it to my OP. Your answer satisfied the question. Thank you for the time.  Turns out, when making a minimal reproducible example, I figured it out.
